# How to properly link libwebrtc with a basic C++ program, on Linux platforms?

Tags: c++, webrtc, undefined-reference

I did some changes to webrtc C++ native implementation, which I successfully compiled using the ninja build system. Then, I tried to compile and link the code example in this repository https://github.com/MemeTao/webrtc-native-examples/tree/master/src/video-channel to libwebrtc.a , but it fails with an undefined reference error, as shown below:

```
/home/stefan/webrtc-samples/src/video-channel/Obj/main.o: In function `main':
/home/stefan/webrtc-samples/src/video-channel/main.cpp:221: undefined reference to `webrtc::CreatePeerConnectionFactory(rtc::Thread*, rtc::Thread*, rtc::Thread*, rtc::scoped_refptr<webrtc::AudioDeviceModule>, rtc::scoped_refptr<webrtc::AudioEncoderFactory>, rtc::scoped_refptr<webrtc::AudioDecoderFactory>, std::unique_ptr<webrtc::VideoEncoderFactory, std::default_delete<webrtc::VideoEncoderFactory> >, std::unique_ptr<webrtc::VideoDecoderFactory, std::default_delete<webrtc::VideoDecoderFactory> >, rtc::scoped_refptr<webrtc::AudioMixer>, rtc::scoped_refptr<webrtc::AudioProcessing>)'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I understood there could be an issue given by the fact that the Google build system uses libc++ implementation of the C++ standard, instead of libstdc++. Thus, I generated the build files such that this library is not used, using the options illustrated below. Besides, I opted for deactiveting the tests and the debug symbols for yielding a lightweight library and I deactivated the clang chrome plugins which might have caused incompatibilities.

`gn gen out --args="is_debug=false rtc_include_tests=false is_component_build=false use_rtti=true use_custom_libcxx=false rtc_enable_protobuf=false clang_use_chrome_plugins=false"`

For building the executable, I use a makefile, listed below. As it can eb seen, I chose the clang compiler, the same used for building libwebrtc, I linked to libstdc++ and I linked to libwebrtc.a which resides in the same folder with the implementation files and the makefile, such that it is found at link time. Additionally, it can eb observed there are used more webrtc defined types in the code from this repository https://github.com/MemeTao/webrtc-native-examples/tree/master/src/video-channel, nevertheless the issue is related only to the CreatePeerConnectionFactory method. Has anyone solved this issue?

```
CC = clang++
CFLAGS = -Wall -g -DWEBRTC_POSIX -std=c++17 -stdlib=libstdc++

SRC_DIR = $(PWD)
SRC_FILES = $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.cpp) $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*/*.cpp) 

OBJ_DIR = $(PWD)/Obj
OBJ_FILES = $(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp, $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o, $(SRC_FILES)) 
ADDITIONAL_OBJ_FILES = $(PWD)/Deps/*.o

WEBRTC_OBJ_PATH = ~/webrtc-l4s/webrtc_native/m104/src/out/Default2/obj
INCLUDES_PATH = -I../../third_party/webrtc/ -I../../third_party/webrtc/third_party/abseil-cpp/ -I../../third_party/webrtc/buildtools/third_party
LIBRARIES_PATH = -L../../third_party/webrtc/buildtools/third_party
#use portable -pthread instead of classic -lpthread
LIBS = -pthread -ldl -L. -lwebrtc  


BIN_DIR = $(PWD)/Bin
TARGET_BINARY = $(BIN_DIR)/demoWebrtc.bin

all: $(TARGET_BINARY)
    @echo "[Build log] Target binary successfully built!"

$(TARGET_BINARY): $(OBJ_FILES)
    @echo "[Build log] Linking..." 
    @echo $(ADDITIONAL_OBJ_FILES)
    $(CC) $(LIBRARIES_PATH) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)
    @echo "[Build log] Program linked!" 

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
    @echo "[Build log] Compiling..."
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES_PATH) -c $< -o $@
    @echo "[Build log] File" $< "compiled!"  

clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJ_DIR)/*.o
    rm -rf $(BIN_DIR)/*.bin
```